# How can I use result variable from out of the lambda function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to get data from external API. This is my Typescript function:

```
export class BarChartcomponent implements OnInit{
  public chart: any;
  data: any = [];
  
  constructor(private service:PostService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.service.getPosts().subscribe(response => {
     this.data = response;
    });
    
    this.createChart();
  };
}
```

I want to use "data" variable for further data manipulations, but when I try to use it outside the subscribe function it result "undefined". I know that is a scope error but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You don't show the code where you use `this.data`. Could it be that the subscribe function is called asynchronously and you use `this.data` _before_ it has been assigned?

Comment: Oh, i use the variable in a function below ngOnInit(). Yes, it's possibile that subscribe is asycronous... i'm pretty newbie on typescript/angular

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score -1):

you have 2 way
1: use promise and then to know when data recived
2: call your method in subscribe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If `this.data` becomes available only asynchronously, you can use a promise:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.data = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    this.service.getPosts().subscribe(response => {
      resolve(response);
    });
  }.bind(this));
  this.createChart(); // this function cannot yet access this.data
}
```

Then, instead of using `this.data` directly in a synchronous function:

```
someFunction() {
  console.log(this.data);
}
```

you must `await` its value in an asynchronous function:

```
async someFunction() {
  console.log(await this.data);
}
```

Note that this make the `someFunction` also asynchronous, so that its return value (if it has any), must also be `await`ed. You can never get rid of asynchronousness once it is introduced.